# Instruments crashing while using Leaks instrument

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, instruments

Ok, so heres the issue. I'm attempting to debug an app with instruments but every time i try to use the Leaks instrument Instruments crashes about 3 seconds into it. This only occurs when i try to use it with an actual device, it will run fine when its just attached to the simulator.

I have reinstalled Xcode and Instruments on 2 different computers, and am running the latest version. This isn't an issue with the app either because i have tried it with 2 other apps and the same thing happens. Also, i have tried this with multiple different devices and the same thing is happening.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

I was just experiencing 100% reproducible crashes in Instruments (not very productive) that seem to have been fixed by rebuilding the spotlight index (`sudo mdutil -E /`), so that might be worth a try for anyone who can't get Instruments to run for more than a few seconds.

Comment: LOL - maybe it has a leak?

Comment: This helped for 3 - 5 seconds :(

Answer (score 0):

Before running you instruments, go to:

```
File->Recording Options->disable "Record reference counts"
```

Comment: Not a real solution if you want to record reference counts which odds are you do.