# SIGSEGV(Bad Memory Access) error while profiling in Instruments

Tags: ios, swift, crash, instruments

I'm trying to catch memory leak and retain cycles with Leak Profiler in Instruments tool. However, whenever I click the record button in Instruments, app looks like to start then crash. If I open the app from Xcode and transfer it to Instruments, App crash after I click any of the `UIButton`. If I open app from Simulator, I can get the second screen but then It also crashes. In addition, App doesn't show any leak in memory graph and also doesn't crash on normal usage.

Here is the crash log;

> > Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000018 VM Region Info: 0x18 is not
> >     in any region.  Bytes before following region: 4377985000
> >           REGION TYPE                      START - END             [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
> >           UNUSED SPACE AT START
> >     --->
> >           __TEXT                 0000000104f2c000-0000000104fbc000 [  576K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  ...ti App Test]
>
> Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11 Termination Reason:
>   Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
>   Triggered by Thread:  0
>
> Filtered syslog: None found
>
> Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread Thread 0
>   Crashed: 0   libswiftCore.dylib               0x000000010597b2b4
>   0x1058cc000 + 717492 1   libswiftCore.dylib
>     0x000000010598823c 0x1058cc000 + 770620 2   UIFoundation
>     0x000000018f01fbdc attributeDictionaryHash + 460 3   Foundation
>     0x0000000185417edc hashProbe + 72 4   Foundation
>     0x0000000185417e7c -[NSConcreteHashTable getItem:] + 40 5
>   UIFoundation                      0x000000018f01fd54
>   +[NSAttributeDictionary newWithDictionary:] + 136 6   Foundation                      0x000000018542666c -[NSConcreteAttributedString
>   initWithString:attributes:] + 124 7   My App Test
>     0x0000000104fbb894 0x104f2c000 + 587924 8   My App Test
>     0x0000000104fba588 0x104f2c000 + 583048 9   My App Test
>     0x0000000104fba494 0x104f2c000 + 582804 10  My App Test
>     0x0000000104fb9964 0x104f2c000 + 579940 11  My App Test
>     0x0000000104fb9830 0x104f2c000 + 579632 12  My App Test
>     0x0000000104fcb608 0x104f2c000 + 652808 13  My App Test
>     0x0000000104fccea4 0x104f2c000 + 659108 14  My App Test
>     0x0000000104fcc50c 0x104f2c000 + 656652 15  My App Test
>     0x0000000104fcc5a0 0x104f2c000 + 656800 16  UIKit
>     0x000000018df36bfc -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1040 17 
>   UIKit                             0x000000018df367d4 -[UIViewController
>   view] + 28 18  My App Test                0x0000000104f85b6c 0x104f2c000
>   + 367468 19  My App Test              0x0000000104f85470 0x104f2c000 + 365680 20  My App Test                 0x0000000104f85688 0x104f2c000 +
>   366216 21  UIKit                          0x000000018df6b20c
>   -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 96 22  UIKit                          0x000000018df6b18c -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 80 23 
>   UIKit                             0x000000018df55f4c -[UIControl
>   _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 440 24  UIKit                             0x000000018df6aa80 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 576 25 
>   UIKit                             0x000000018df6a5a0 -[UIWindow
>   _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2544 26  UIKit                           0x000000018df65a70 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 3208 27  UIKit
>     0x000000018df37078 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 340 28  UIKit
>     0x000000018e876f98 **dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 2364
>   29  UIKit                             0x000000018e879408
>   __handleEventQueueInternal + 4760 30  UIKit                           0x000000018e872574 __handleHIDEventFetcherDrain + 152 31 
>   CoreFoundation                    0x0000000184ad0358
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 24 32  CoreFoundation                    0x0000000184ad02d8 __CFRunLoopDoSource0
>   + 88 33  CoreFoundation                   0x0000000184acfb60 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 204 34  CoreFoundation                   0x0000000184acd738 __CFRunLoopRun + 1048 35  CoreFoundation
>     0x00000001849ee2d8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436 36  GraphicsServices
>     0x000000018687ff84 GSEventRunModal + 100 37  UIKit
>     0x000000018df9a880 UIApplicationMain + 208 38  My App Test
>     0x0000000104f97854 0x104f2c000 + 440404 39  libdyld.dylib
>     0x000000018451256c start + 4
>
> Thread 1: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000184641dbc
>   __workq_kernreturn + 8 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000184753144 _pthread_wqthread + 1288 2
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x0000000184752c30 start_wqthread + 4
>
> Thread 2: 0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184752c2c
>   start_wqthread + 0
>
> Thread 3 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread Thread 3: 0
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x0000000184620bc4 mach_msg_trap + 8 1 
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x0000000184620a3c mach_msg + 72 2
>   CoreFoundation                    0x0000000184acfce4
>   **CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196 3   CoreFoundation                   0x0000000184acd8b0 __CFRunLoopRun + 1424 4   CoreFoundation
>
>     0x00000001849ee2d8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436 5   Foundation
>
>     0x00000001854166e4 -[NSRunLoop+ 50916 (NSRunLoop)
>   runMode:beforeDate:] + 304 6   Foundation
>
>     0x0000000185435afc -[NSRunLoop+ 178940 (NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] +
>   96 7   UIKit                          0x000000018eae602c
>   -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 136 8   Foundation                     0x0000000185517860 __NSThread__start** + 996 9
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x000000018475432c _pthread_body + 308
>   10  libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00000001847541f8 _pthread_body +
>   0 11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184752c38 thread_start +
>   4
>
> Thread 4: 0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184752c2c
>   start_wqthread + 0
>
> Thread 5 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader Thread 5: 0
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x0000000184620bc4 mach_msg_trap + 8 1 
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x0000000184620a3c mach_msg + 72 2
>   CoreFoundation                    0x0000000184acfce4
>   **CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196 3   CoreFoundation                   0x0000000184acd8b0 __CFRunLoopRun + 1424 4   CoreFoundation
>
>     0x00000001849ee2d8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436 5   CFNetwork
>
>     0x0000000185157b40 +[NSURLConnection+ 715584 (Loader)
>   _resourceLoadLoop:] + 404 6   Foundation                      0x0000000185517860 __NSThread__start** + 996 7
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x000000018475432c _pthread_body + 308
>   8   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00000001847541f8 _pthread_body +
>   0 9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184752c38 thread_start +
>   4
>
> Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
>       x0: 0x00000001c4227ac0   x1: 0x000000018eca2db2   x2: 0x000000016aecf908   x3: 0x0000000000000000
>       x4: 0x0000000000000000   x5: 0x0000000000000020   x6: 0x0000000185426654   x7: 0x0000000000000130
>       x8: 0x0000000000000000   x9: 0x0000000000000000  x10: 0x0119490101194980  x11: 0x0000000001194901    x12: 0x0000000001194800
>   x13: 0x0000000000000001  x14: 0x0000000000000000  x15:
>   0x01194901011949c0    x16: 0x0000000000000000  x17: 0x0000000105988228
>   x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x00000001c4227ac0    x20:
>   0x00000001c4227ac0  x21: 0x00000001b5421000  x22: 0x00000001c0124f60 
>   x23: 0x0000000000000000    x24: 0x00000001c0200730  x25:
>   0x0000000000000000  x26: 0x000000018eca3f46  x27: 0x00000001b3bca000
>   x28: 0x00000001c04578e0   fp: 0x000000016aecf4f0   lr:
>   0x000000010598823c
>       sp: 0x000000016aecf4e0   pc: 0x000000010597b2b4 cpsr: 0x20000000

I was searching this for a month and I'm not sure If It is a Instruments bug. I checked below posts;

[Xcode Instruments: Leaks - App crashes on launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49940506/xcode-instruments-leaks-app-crashes-on-launch)

[Instruments crashing while using Leaks instrument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10926443/instruments-crashing-while-using-leaks-instrument)

[xcode instruments causing app crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372553/xcode-instruments-causing-app-crash)

EDIT: Another crash log. In this one I open the app and transfer memory to Instruments tool and touch a UIView top open a new controller.

> > Date/Time:           2018-07-06 15:13:34.5980 +0300 Launch Time:         2018-07-06 15:13:19.6298 +0300 OS Version:          iPhone OS 11.0
> >     (15A372) Baseband Version:    2.00.01 Report Version:      104
>
> Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) Exception Subtype:
>   KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000018 VM Region Info: 0x18 is not
>   in any region.  Bytes before following region: 4330094568
>         REGION TYPE                      START - END             [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
>         UNUSED SPACE AT START
>   --->
>         __TEXT                 0000000102180000-00000001022a0000 [ 1152K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  ...ti Filo Test]
>
> Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11 Termination Reason:
>   Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
>   Triggered by Thread:  0
>
> Filtered syslog: None found
>
> Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread Thread 0
>   Crashed: 0   libswiftCore.dylib               0x0000000102bdf278
>   0x102b30000 + 717432 1   libswiftCore.dylib
>     0x0000000102bec1b0 0x102b30000 + 770480 2   CoreFoundation
>     0x0000000184a3ec80 -[NSDictionary allKeys] + 108 3   UIKit
>     0x000000018e15738c -[NSDictionary+ 2294668
>   (UIStringDrawingKeyCompatibility)
>   _ui_attributesForDictionaryContainingUIStringDrawingKeys] + 36 4   UIKit                          0x000000018e09fde0 -[UINavigationBar
>   setTitleTextAttributes:] + 144 5   My App Test
>     0x00000001021e82e8 0x102180000 + 426728 6   My App Test
>     0x00000001021e67c8 0x102180000 + 419784 7   My App Test
>     0x00000001021e6a14 0x102180000 + 420372 8   UIKit
>     0x000000018e5c3f78 -[UIGestureRecognizerTarget
>   _sendActionWithGestureRecognizer:] + 64 9   UIKit                             0x000000018e5c84dc _UIGestureRecognizerSendTargetActions + 124 10 
>   UIKit                             0x000000018e0b2dc8
>   _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 320 11  UIKit                           0x000000018df67748 -[UIGestureRecognizer
>   _updateGestureWithEvent:buttonEvent:] + 732 12  UIKit                             0x000000018e5b23fc _UIGestureEnvironmentUpdate + 1056 13  UIKit
>     0x000000018e5b1f88 -[UIGestureEnvironment
>   _deliverEvent:toGestureRecognizers:usingBlock:] + 404 14  UIKit                           0x000000018e5b10e4 -[UIGestureEnvironment
>   _updateGesturesForEvent:window:] + 276 15  UIKit                          0x000000018df65a54 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 3180 16  UIKit
>     0x000000018df37078 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 340 17  UIKit
>     0x000000018e876f98 **dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 2364
>   18  UIKit                             0x000000018e879408
>   __handleEventQueueInternal + 4760 19  UIKit                           0x000000018e872574 __handleHIDEventFetcherDrain + 152 20 
>   CoreFoundation                    0x0000000184ad0358
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 24 21  CoreFoundation                    0x0000000184ad02d8 __CFRunLoopDoSource0
>   + 88 22  CoreFoundation                   0x0000000184acfb60 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 204 23  CoreFoundation                   0x0000000184acd738 __CFRunLoopRun + 1048 24  CoreFoundation
>     0x00000001849ee2d8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436 25  GraphicsServices
>     0x000000018687ff84 GSEventRunModal + 100 26  UIKit
>     0x000000018df9a880 UIApplicationMain + 208 27  My App Test
>     0x00000001021facdc 0x102180000 + 503004 28  libdyld.dylib
>     0x000000018451256c start + 4
>
> Thread 1: 0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184752c2c
>   start_wqthread + 0
>
> Thread 2: 0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184752c2c
>   start_wqthread + 0
>
> Thread 3: 0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184752c2c
>   start_wqthread + 0
>
> Thread 4 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread Thread 4: 0
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x0000000184620bc4 mach_msg_trap + 8 1 
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x0000000184620a3c mach_msg + 72 2
>   CoreFoundation                    0x0000000184acfce4
>   **CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196 3   CoreFoundation                   0x0000000184acd8b0 __CFRunLoopRun + 1424 4   CoreFoundation
>
>     0x00000001849ee2d8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436 5   Foundation
>
>     0x00000001854166e4 -[NSRunLoop+ 50916 (NSRunLoop)
>   runMode:beforeDate:] + 304 6   Foundation
>
>     0x0000000185435afc -[NSRunLoop+ 178940 (NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] +
>   96 7   UIKit                          0x000000018eae602c
>   -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 136 8   Foundation                     0x0000000185517860 __NSThread__start** + 996 9
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x000000018475432c _pthread_body + 308
>   10  libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00000001847541f8 _pthread_body +
>   0 11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184752c38 thread_start +
>   4
>
> Thread 5 name:  GAIThread Thread 5: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib
>     0x0000000184620bc4 mach_msg_trap + 8 1   libsystem_kernel.dylib
>     0x0000000184620a3c mach_msg + 72 2   CoreFoundation
>     0x0000000184acfce4 **CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196 3
>
>   CoreFoundation                    0x0000000184acd8b0 __CFRunLoopRun +
>   1424 4   CoreFoundation                   0x00000001849ee2d8
>   CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436 5   Foundation
>
>     0x00000001854166e4 -[NSRunLoop+ 50916 (NSRunLoop)
>   runMode:beforeDate:] + 304 6   Foundation
>
>     0x000000018546862c -[NSRunLoop+ 386604 (NSRunLoop) run] + 88 7   My
>   App Test              0x000000010225b108 0x102180000 + 897288 8
>
>   Foundation                        0x0000000185517860 __NSThread__start**
>   + 996 9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018475432c _pthread_body + 308 10  libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x00000001847541f8 _pthread_body + 0 11  libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x0000000184752c38 thread_start + 4
>
> Thread 6 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader Thread 6: 0
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x0000000184620bc4 mach_msg_trap + 8 1 
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x0000000184620a3c mach_msg + 72 2
>   CoreFoundation                    0x0000000184acfce4
>   **CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196 3   CoreFoundation                   0x0000000184acd8b0 __CFRunLoopRun + 1424 4   CoreFoundation
>
>     0x00000001849ee2d8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436 5   CFNetwork
>
>     0x0000000185157b40 +[NSURLConnection+ 715584 (Loader)
>   _resourceLoadLoop:] + 404 6   Foundation                      0x0000000185517860 __NSThread__start** + 996 7
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x000000018475432c _pthread_body + 308
>   8   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00000001847541f8 _pthread_body +
>   0 9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184752c38 thread_start +
>   4
>
> Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
>       x0: 0x00000001c4227c60   x1: 0x000000018eca2db2   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x000000010637e8d0
>       x4: 0x0000000000000002   x5: 0x0000000000000020   x6: 0x00000001021e82e8   x7: 0x0000000000000b70
>       x8: 0x0000000000000000   x9: 0x0000000000000000  x10: 0x01446b0101446b80  x11: 0x0000000001446b01    x12: 0x0000000001446a00
>   x13: 0x0000000000000001  x14: 0x0000000000000000  x15:
>   0x01446b0101446bc0    x16: 0x0000000000000000  x17: 0x0000000102bec19c
>   x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x00000001c4227c60    x20:
>   0x00000001c4227c60  x21: 0x00000001c4227c60  x22: 0x00000000000000d0 
>   x23: 0x00000000000001f0    x24: 0x0000000000000008  x25:
>   0x00000001c4107740  x26: 0x00000001c40ca6b0  x27: 0x00000001c4093330
>   x28: 0x00000001b3f8f000   fp: 0x000000016dc7ce40   lr:
>   0x0000000102bec1b0
>       sp: 0x000000016dc7ce30   pc: 0x0000000102bdf278 cpsr: 0x20000000

**EDIT:** After @FranticRock s' answer. When I delete **[UINavigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:]** detail class can open but none of the items (title, back button or any cell) is shown. They are all empty and I'm still getting leaks.

Here is the controller class where where I write **[UINavigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:]**

```
class WelcomeViewController: BaseViewController {

let bgView = UIView()
let backgroundImage = UIImageView()

let logoImage: UIImageView = {
    let i = UIImageView()
    i.image = UIImage(named: "full_logo")
    i.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    return i
}()

let welcomeLabel : UILabel = {
    let l = UILabel()
    l.font = Fonts.font.withSize(24)
    l.textColor = UIColor.white
    l.textAlignment = .center
    l.numberOfLines = 0
    l.sizeToFit()
    return l
}()

let loginLbl: UILabel = {
    let l = UILabel()
    l.font = Fonts.font.withSize(13)
    l.textColor = UIColor.white
    l.textAlignment = .center
    l.numberOfLines = 0
    l.sizeToFit()
    return l
}()

let adminBtn: UIButton = {
    let b = UIButton()
    b.backgroundColor = Color.Common.buttonColor
    b.layer.cornerRadius = 6.0
    return b
}()

let userBtn: UIButton = {
    let b = UIButton()
    b.backgroundColor = Color.Common.buttonColor
    b.layer.cornerRadius = 6.0
    return b
}()

lazy var supportedServicesView = WelcomeScreenButtonView(text: getLabelText(key: CMSKeys.CMS_LBL_SUPPORTEDSERVICES), imageName: "phone")
lazy var incidentView = WelcomeScreenButtonView(text: getLabelText(key: CMSKeys.CMS_LBL_INCIDENT), imageName: "phone")
lazy var contactUsView = WelcomeScreenButtonView(text: getLabelText(key:CMSKeys.CMS_LBL_CONTACT), imageName: "phone")
lazy var moreView = WelcomeScreenButtonView(text: getLabelText(key:CMSKeys.CMS_LBL_MORE), imageName: "wdiger")

lazy var emergencyBtn = SendButton(text: "Button")

let firstStackView = UIStackView()
let secondStackView = UIStackView()
let thirdStackView = UIStackView()

let btnStackView = UIStackView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.setPageID()
    designUI()
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if(AppContext.instance.comesFromURL != nil){
        comesFromURL()
    }
}
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if(analyticsName != nil){
        self.sendDataToGA()
    }
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

    bgView.anchor(self.thirdStackView.topAnchor, left: self.view.leftAnchor, bottom: self.view.bottomAnchor, right: self.view.rightAnchor, topConstant: 40, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 0)

    let margins = view.layoutMarginsGuide
    thirdStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.leadingAnchor,constant: 5).isActive = true
    thirdStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.trailingAnchor,constant: -5).isActive = true
    thirdStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.emergencyBtn.topAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    thirdStackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: thirdStackView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.77).isActive = true

    emergencyBtn.anchor(nil, left: self.view.leftAnchor, bottom: self.bottomLayoutGuide.topAnchor, right: self.view.rightAnchor, topConstant: 10, leftConstant: 20, bottomConstant: 20, rightConstant: 20, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 48)
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        logoImage.anchor(self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, left: self.view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: self.view.rightAnchor, topConstant: 40, leftConstant: 80, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 80, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 0)
    } else {
        logoImage.anchor(self.view.topAnchor, left: self.view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: self.view.rightAnchor, topConstant: 40, leftConstant: 80, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 80, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 0)
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
    logoImage.anchorCenterXToSuperview()
    let welcomeLblHeight = heightForView(text: "Welcome", font: welcomeLabel.font, width: self.view.bounds.width)
    let loginLblHeight = heightForView(text: "Please Log In", font: loginLbl.font, width: self.view.bounds.width)
    welcomeLabel.anchor(self.logoImage.bottomAnchor, left: self.view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: self.view.rightAnchor, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 50, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 50, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: welcomeLblHeight)
    loginLbl.anchor(self.welcomeLabel.bottomAnchor, left: self.view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: self.view.rightAnchor, topConstant: 10, leftConstant: 50, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 50, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: loginLblHeight)
    btnStackView.anchor(nil, left: self.view.leftAnchor, bottom: self.thirdStackView.topAnchor, right: self.view.rightAnchor, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 20, bottomConstant: 20, rightConstant: 20, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 50)

    backgroundImage.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height - self.bgView.frame.height)
}

private func designUI(){
    self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
    backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: "background.png")
    backgroundImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    self.view.insertSubview(backgroundImage, at: 0)

    bgView.backgroundColor = Color.Common.welcomeScreenBackgroundColor
    self.view.insertSubview(bgView, at: 1)
    view.addSubview(logoImage)
    welcomeLabel.text = getLabelText(key: CMSKeys.CMS_LBL_WELCOME)
    view.addSubview(welcomeLabel)
    loginLbl.text = getLabelText(key: CMSKeys.CMS_LBL_LOGIN)
    view.addSubview(loginLbl)

    adminBtn.backgroundColor = Color.Common.adminGreen
    adminBtn.setTitle(getLabelText(key: CMSKeys.CMS_BTN_ADMIN), for: .normal)
    adminBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(adminBtnTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    userBtn.backgroundColor = Color.Common.userGreen
    userBtn.setTitle(getLabelText(key: CMSKeys.CMS_BTN_USER), for: .normal)
    userBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(userBtnTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    btnStackView.axis  = UILayoutConstraintAxis.horizontal
    btnStackView.distribution = UIStackViewDistribution.fillEqually
    btnStackView.alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.fill
    btnStackView.spacing = 10.0
    btnStackView.addArrangedSubview(adminBtn)
    btnStackView.addArrangedSubview(userBtn)
    btnStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.view.addSubview(btnStackView)

    firstStackView.axis  = UILayoutConstraintAxis.vertical
    firstStackView.distribution = UIStackViewDistribution.fillEqually
    firstStackView.alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.fill
    firstStackView.spacing = 10.0
    firstStackView.addArrangedSubview(supportedServicesView)
    firstStackView.addArrangedSubview(contactUsView)
    firstStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    secondStackView.axis  = UILayoutConstraintAxis.vertical
    secondStackView.distribution = UIStackViewDistribution.fillEqually
    secondStackView.alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.fill
    secondStackView.spacing = 10.0
    secondStackView.addArrangedSubview(incidentView)
    secondStackView.addArrangedSubview(moreView)
    secondStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    thirdStackView.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxis.horizontal
    thirdStackView.distribution = UIStackViewDistribution.fillEqually
    thirdStackView.alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.fill
    thirdStackView.spacing = 10.0
    thirdStackView.addArrangedSubview(firstStackView)
    thirdStackView.addArrangedSubview(secondStackView)
    thirdStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(thirdStackView)

    //View Tap Gestures
    let tapSupportedServices = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tapSupportedServices(_:)))
    supportedServicesView.addGestureRecognizer(tapSupportedServices)
    supportedServicesView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    let tapIncidentView = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tapIncident(_:)))
    incidentView.addGestureRecognizer(tapIncidentView)
    incidentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    let tapContactUs = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tapContactUs(_:)))
    contactUsView.addGestureRecognizer(tapContactUs)
    contactUsView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    let tapMoreView = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tapMore(_:)))
    moreView.addGestureRecognizer(tapMoreView)
    moreView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    emergencyBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 6.0
    emergencyBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(emergenyBtnTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(emergencyBtn)

}

@objc func tapSupportedServices(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let linkingVC = SupportedServicesFirstViewController()
    let controller = createNavController(title: "Services", viewController: linkingVC)
    self.present(controller, animated: true)
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

private func heightForView(text:String, font:UIFont, width:CGFloat) -> CGFloat{
    let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
    label.font = font
    label.text = text
    label.sizeToFit()

    return label.frame.height
}

//Gets a Title and a ViewController then returns a UINavigationController with attributes
private func createNavController(title: String, viewController: UIViewController) -> UINavigationController {
    viewController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.87, green:0.87, blue:0.87, alpha:1.0)
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
    navController.navigationBar.topItem?.title = title
    navController.navigationBar.barTintColor = Color.NavigationBar.tintColor
    navController.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
    //Fix: Leak
    navController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: Color.NavigationBar.textColor]

    return navController
}

private func removeViews(){
    self.emergencyBtn.removeFromSuperview()
    self.incidentView.removeFromSuperview()
    self.moreView.removeFromSuperview()
    self.supportedServicesView.removeFromSuperview()
    self.contactUsView.removeFromSuperview()
}
deinit {
    print("Welcome Deinited")
    removeViews()
}
}
```

Comment: In all probability the reason you crash when profiling but not normally is that profiling uses a Release build.

Comment: Profiling in release isnt it the right way?

Comment: Absolutely yes. But the point is that this is evidently bringing out a threading problem that a Debug build doesn't; otherwise you'd see the issue when you just build and run from Xcode. So what I'm saying is, try changing the scheme so that build-and-run uses a Release build, and see if I'm right (i.e. you crash). If so, this has nothing to do with Instruments, and now your question becomes just a duplicate of all the other threading-issue EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash questions. But if I'm wrong, then something about the Leaks instrument particularly may be at fault (and you should file a bug).

Comment: `EXC_BAD_ACCESS `: Maybe its cause sth was freed before use because there was no strong reference to it? I don‘t know whether `self.present(..)` holds a strong reference afterwards. Just a shot in the dark though. UINavigationController deiniting and taking the UINavigationBar with it is definietly possible. Maybe derive UINavigationController, add a deinit with a print-line and see whether it deinits too early.

Answer (score 4):

In the first stack trace, there is code related to: **[UINavigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:]**
It's trying to customize the navigation bar by setting text attributes on the title. Are you doing that?   Can you try commenting that out, and see if the problem goes away?

Technically what you have is not a memory leak.  You are accessing a deallocated object.  One other thing you can do is enable Zombie Objects, on the scheme which you are running, and see if you can get info on which object got deallocated.

Now if none of the stack traces above lead you to any of the code you directly wrote, and you say that you used the Memory Debug Graph tool already and did not find any strong references to any objects you are checking for leaks, I would use a more creative approach here to find the problem.   The approach I often use is elimination.  Start commenting out large parts of your controller, until you are left with just the empty shell.  Each time, you can cut the code in half (log performance), and re-test which part of the code references the object which was deallocated.

Obviously since normal app operation doesn't result in a Bad Access Exception, it's likely related to XCode / Instruments internals, however the **setTitleTextAttributes** above looks suspicious, and I would first try to narrow down whether the issue is related to the Navigation Bar. Are you doing anything strange with the navigation hierarchy or customization of your navbar UI?

Also check whether other instances of that same View Controller exist in memory from previous navigation events / instances...  It sounds like a UI object is getting dealloced, and then being updated by an async process later.

Also override your deinit { }. method and put a print statement inside, to detect all related objects being deallocated.  This will help narrow down, which controller is being deallocated and accessed later.

Does it occur on all iOS Version / Device models or specific ones only?

Comment: I'll check it on monday and write details. Thank you.

Comment: When I comment [UINavigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:], new controller which has an UITableView opened but neither back navigation button or tableview has any item on it.

Comment: Where in your code is setTitleTextAttributes being done?  Which View Controller lifecycle method?   viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear, etc . Did you override deinit { print("VC Deinit")?    Is your view controller being Deinit before the code to setTitleTextAttributse is being called?    If so, why is it being deinit?   It would be helpful to post your code.  (You could remove business-specific details and just post the skeleton code which exhibits the same problem you reported)

Comment: One thing right off the bat is: you have to call the overriden methods:  super.viewWillAppear and super.viewDidAppear.  (And make sure your BaseViewController also calls super in both methods).   It's strongly recommended.

Comment: I added it to both controllers but nothing affected on leak side.

Comment: When you are declaring the linkingVC, it's not done from storyboard?  You are doing all VC init inside constructor?  Have you tried to postpone the call to setTitleTextAttributes until the completion block of present() gets called? Maybe the VC has issues setting title attributes too early in it's lifecycle. Another experiment is:  try holding both the linkingVC and the navController on the top of your controller strongly (heap variable), to see if it would prevent them from being dealloced (while presented).  May have to do with how you create your controller in init without a decoder.

Comment: Another thing to try:  instead of passing .  linkingVC, pass some other blank VC, and see if the problem still exists.  This will narrow it down, to whether it's related to the linkingVC, or the way you are presenting the nav VC.

Comment: Great comments @FranticRock I'll check all of them and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues being raised by the question.  The first is why profiling is broken, and the second is why your application has a use-after-free issue.

@FranicRock has offered great suggestions on the second issue.

My suggestion for the profiling problem is to try a workaround.  If your application can be compiled with the (as of writing) Beta Xcode 10.0 then you can go into Edit Schema (`Command-<`) and in the Diagnostics Tab for your Run action, Click on **Logging Malloc Stack** with sub-option **All Allocation and Free History**.  Then you can:

1. Run your app in the simulator.
2. Press the memory graph button in the debugger area (8th icon which looks like three circles joined together)
3. Do File->Export Memory Graph.

You can either study the memory graph yourself or put it in a public location like Pastebin for others to provide insights.  Apple have an informative video on this new approach: [WWDC-2018-416-Memory-Deep-Dive](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/416/?time=666)